# ¿Para qué, cómo y cuándo utilizar las palabras reservadas 'use' y 'namespace'?

Tags: php

Ni el manual de PHP me lo ha podido aclarar.

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Por favor, lee esta guía _"[ask]"_ y asegúrate que tu pregunta cumple con lo indicado en esa publicación.

Answer (score 2):

### Espacios de nombre o `namespace`

Creo que para poder entender un poco, conviene explicar qué son los espacios de nombres.

Lo que pasa es que el Manual habla de ellos en diferentes partes. No sé si has leído [esta parte del Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.rationale.php):

> ¿Qué son los espacios de nombres?
>
> En su definición más aceptada, los espacios de nombres son una manera
>   de encapsular elementos. Se pueden ver como un concepto abstracto en
>   muchos aspectos. Por ejemplo, en cualquier sistema operativo, los
>   directorios sirven para agrupar ficheros relacionados, actuando así
>   como espacios de nombres para los ficheros que contienen. Como
>   ejemplo, el fichero `foo.txt` puede existir en los directorios
>   `/home/greg` y `/home/otro`, pero no pueden coexistir dos copias de
>   `foo.txt` en el mismo directorio.
>
> Además, para acceder al fichero `foo.txt` fuera del directorio
>   `/home/greg`, se debe anteponer el nombre del directorio al nombre del
>   fichero, empleando el separador de directorios para así obtener
>   `/home/greg/foo.txt`. **Este mismo principio se extiende a los
>   espacios de nombres en el mundo de la programación.**

#### Uso en PHP

En el mundo de PHP, los espacios de nombres están diseñados para solucionar dos problemas con los que se encuentran los autores de bibliotecas y de aplicaciones al crear elementos de código reusable, tales como clases o funciones:

1. El conflicto de nombres entre el código que se crea y las clases/funciones/constantes internas de PHP o las clases/funciones/constantes de terceros.
2. La capacidad de apodar (o abreviar) Nombres_Extra_Largos diseñada para aliviar el primer problema, mejorando la legibilidad del código fuente.
   Los espacios de nombres de PHP proporcionan una manera para agrupar clases, interfaces, funciones y constantes relacionadas.

---

Otros enlaces del Manual que tratan el tema:

- [Espacios de nombres](http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.php) (con una tabla de contenidos)
- [La palabra reservada namespace y la constante **NAMESPACE**](http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php)
- [Uso de los espacios de nombres: apodar/importar](http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php)
- [Uso de los espacios de nombres: lo básico](http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.basics.php)

También puedes leer este artículo que lo explica muy bien:

- [Namespaces en PHP](https://diego.com.es/namespaces-en-php)

---

### `use`

Está relacionada con los espacios de nombres.

El [Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php) dice que se encarga de la acción de apodar, de dar un nombre. Podría ser considerado un sinónimo de `import` en otros lenguajes.

> La capacidad de referirse a un nombre completamente cualificado
>   externo con un alias, o importar, es una característca importante de
>   los espacios de nombres. Esto es similar a la capacidad de los
>   sistemas de ficheros basados en Unix de crear enlaces simbólicos a un
>   fichero o directorio.
>
> Todas las versiones de PHP que tienen soporte para espacios de nombres
>   admiten tres tipos de alias o importación: apodar un nombre de clase,
>   apodar un nombre de interfaz, y apodar un nombre de espacio de
>   nombres. PHP 5.6+ también permite apodar o importar nombres de
>   funciones y constantes.
>
> En PHP, la acción de apodar se lleva a cabo con el operador `use`.
>
> La palabra reservada `use` debe ser declarada en el ámbito exterior de
>   un fichero (el ámbito global) o dentro de declaraciones de espacios de
>   nombres. Esto es así debido a que la importación se realiza durante la
>   compilación y no durante la ejecución, por lo que no puede ser
>   utilizada en un ámbito de bloque.

En el enlace de más arriba se muestran ejemplos de `use`.